# Create NSDate from Unix timestamp

Tags: objective-c

How do I create an NSDate from a Unix timestamp?

```
channel.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
(NSTimeInterval)[channelJson objectForKey:@"broadcastStartedTime"]];
```

I get this error:

> 104: error: pointer value used where a
>   floating point value was expected

`channels.startDate` is an `NSDate*`. The value for the key "broadcastStartedTime" is a Javascript `Number` converted into an `NSNumber` or `NSDecimalNumber` by the [SBJson](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) parser library.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
NSNumber *startTime = channelJson[@"broadcastStartedTime"];
channel.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[startTime doubleValue]];
```

Your value is trapped in a pointer type of `NSNumber`.  The `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` method is expecting a primitive `NSTimeInterval` (which, under the covers, is a `double`).

Answer (score 7):

Use `-doubleValue`:

```
// NSTimeInterval is just a typedef for double
NSTimeInterval interval = [[channelJson objectForKey:@"broadcastStartedTime"] doubleValue];
channel.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

Comment: You can't cast an Objective-C object (like NSNumber) to a primitive (like double). Compile-time casting only works from primitive to primitive, or object to object. That's why we had to call the `doubleValue` method; to convert at runtime to a double.

Answer (score 4):

You need to unwrap the NSNumber:

```
channel.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[channelJson objectForKey:@"broadcastStartedTime"] doubleValue]];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/) (which is unix timestmap) to [`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) conversion in Swift:

```
let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 // the the unix timestamp
NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
```