# how to convert a unix timestamp into nsdate in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create NSDate from Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827240/create-nsdate-from-unix-timestamp)

I have an application where i am receiving date from json in unix timestamp format.This is the timestamp that i am receiving from json '1357178589630'.How to convert this timestamp into correct nsdate.I have used the following code for conversion but it is not working properly.This is my code:

```
double timestampval =  [[updates objectForKey:@"timestamp"] doubleValue];
NSTimeInterval timestamp = (NSTimeInterval)timestampval;
NSDate *updatetimestamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
```

When the timestamp is converted to nsdate using datewithtimeIntervalSince1970,in the updatetimestamp variable it displays '44977-04-11 12:40:30 +0000'

Comment: It's giving correct result , seems that your timestamps is incorrect. Try converting your time-stamp here http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: You probably have milliseconds which are used (as far as I know) in Java Date objects. Just divide the value by 1000, then the result is "Thu, 03 Jan 2013 02:03:09 GMT".

Comment: @MartinR : exactly... :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I had not seen that you already had updated your answer with this information.

Comment: @MartinR: No problem dude... many a times multiple answers are posted within a minute...and these answers are almost similar or even same. Its just a luck...

Answer (score 22):

Try this one:

Might be you are getting timestamp is milli seconds instead of seconds, so you divide it by 1000.

EDIT Newer:

```
double timestampval =  [[updates objectForKey:@"timestamp"] doubleValue]/1000;
NSTimeInterval timestamp = (NSTimeInterval)timestampval;
NSDate *updatetimestamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
```

Previous :

```
double unixTimeStamp =1304245000;
NSTimeInterval timeInterval=unixTimeStamp/1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *dateString=[dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Thanks for your old answer. I need to get current local timestamp using unixTimeStamp. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone: use        `NSTimeInterval unixTimeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`

Comment: works , but we need time zone to set here

Answer (score 10):

`[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp]` is correct. Seems that your timestamps is wrong.

Instead `1357178589630` it should be `1357178589`.

Try [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).

**Update:** as per Martin comment above.

Just divide the value by 1000.

Answer (score 2):

try this code..

```
NSDate *dateTraded = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 :[[updates objectForKey:@"timestamp"] integerValue]];
```

and Unix timestamps are in seconds, the value you have looks like a number of milliseconds since 1st January 1970. If you divide by 1000, you get 1264396813, which according to http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm