# Date format of JSON to be parsed in iOS7

Tags: ios, json, date, ios7, date-format

I would like to parse the following JSON response in iOS:

```
"myCaldDate": 1392076800000
```

What is this date format called and how do we parse and display in `dd-mm-yyyy` format in iOS apps and sync the date to device calendar?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if it has a particular name, looks like a milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value, assuming that date represents February 11, 2014 at midnight GMT (The Epoch being midnight, January 1st, 1970 GMT). Whenever you see something that's just a number and it's meant to be a date, odds are it's either seconds-since-The-Epoch or milliseconds-since-The-Epoch.

Comment: Is that a timestamp value? If so, you may check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827240/create-nsdate-from-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(NSDate)dateDiff:(double )myCaldDate
{
   / Date difference for the purpose of showing games listes
   double timeInterval = myCaldDate/1000.0f;
   NSDate *convertedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

   return convertedDate;
}
```

Now Sync :-

```
-(NSString *)syncWithCalender:(NSDate *)convertDate
{

NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
double ti = [convertDate timeIntervalSinceDate:todayDate];
ti = ti * -1;
if(ti <= 1)
{
    return @"Just Now";
}
else if (ti < 60)
{
    return @"less than a minute ago";
}
else if (ti < 3600)
{
    int diff = (ti / 60);
    if (diff==1)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute ago", diff];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes ago", diff];
}
else if (ti < 86400)
{
    int diff = (ti / 60 / 60);
    if (diff == 1)
    {
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hour ago", diff];
    }
    return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours ago", diff];
}
else if (ti < 2629743)
{
    int diff = (ti / 60 / 60 / 24);
    if (diff == 1)
    {
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d day ago", diff];
    }
    return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days ago", diff];
}
else if (ti < 31557600)
{
    int diff = (ti / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30);
    if (diff == 1)
    {
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d month ago", diff];
    }
    return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d months ago", diff];
}
else
{
    int diff = (ti / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30 / 12);
    if (diff == 1)
    {
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d year ago", diff];
    }
    return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d years ago", diff];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the time interval from UNIX date or Epoch as Crowder said.
To create a string date from that you should:

1. Create an NSDate object from that interval
2. Create and set an NSDateFormatter object
3. Create the string from the date formatter

In code:

```
NSDate * date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    //you can choose dofferetnt styles or create your own by using a format string conforms to uni specifications
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    NSString * string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

> -initWithTimeIntervalSince1970: Returns an NSDate object set to the given number of seconds from the first instant of 1 January 1970, GMT.
>
> - (instancetype)initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds Parameters seconds The number of seconds from the reference date, 1
>     January 1970, GMT, for the new date. Use a negative argument to
>     specify a date before this date. Return Value An NSDate object set to
>     seconds seconds from the reference date.
>
> Discussion This method is useful for creating NSDate objects from
>   time_t values returned by BSD system functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[@"1392076800000" doubleValue]/1000];

NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"LLL dd yyyy, hh:mm a"];
NSString *strdate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",strdate);
```